# How to Calculate How Much Time the Program Consumed While Running

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to calculate the time consumed by the program. But what is the difference between the two methods displayed below?

```
System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
```

Comment: The first is using `Modulus` division the second is using regular division...

Comment: your question in the title differes from your question in your post, is this done on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the fact that you're dividing by 1000 you want it in seconds?
Regardless, the modulus operator `%` is not what you want here, it gives you the remainder of the division by the second operand.

To get the runtime of some code, get the current time before execution, and after execution. The runtime will the the difference between the two.

```
System timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
//PUT CODE HERE
System timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();

System timeDelta = timeAfter = timeBefore;
System.out.println("Runtime was " + timeDelta + " millis"); //display milliseconds
System.out.println("Runtime was " + (timeDelta / 1000) + " seconds"); //display seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);//do your work here
    long t2 = System.nanoTime();
    long result = t2 - t1;
    result = result / 1000000000;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This will give you time in seconds...

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score -1):

**Explanation of the two methods**

> System.currentTimeMillis() / `1000`

`/` is the division operator. 
It will return you the result of `System.currentTimeMillis()` divided by `1000`. This is often used to convert miliseconds to seconds.

> System.currentTimeMillis() % `1000`

`%` is the remainder operator. 
It will return the remainder that is left after the division by `1000` (modulus).

Oracle provides a full list of [Java-Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

---

**Example for the question from the title**

If you want to get the total uptime off your application, you can easily receive it from the Java Runtime:

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime()
```

This will return the runtime of your programm in milliseconds. By dividing it with 1000 you will get the seconds your programm is running.

**Advantage**:

- You don't have to handle the time measurement yourself